# device in lspci can't find in dmidecode

Tags: linux

lspci

02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 610] (rev a1)

the pci bus is 02 the deivce id is 00

and why can't find this info in dmidecode

thisi is dmidecode

## dmidecode 2.12-dmifs

SMBIOS 2.7 present.
104 structures occupying 5095 bytes.
Table at 0x000EB110.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SMBIOS information is a little bit limited - If you look at [the latest specification](https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.0.0.pdf) in section 7 it indicates the structures that would be populated in the information tables. Things like baseboard, etc. The list is pretty self-explanatory, and generally includes the slots exposed by the motherboard and whether they're occupied or not.

The issue is that it relies on the BIOS vendor to populate everything - if they choose not to populate a type 10/type 41 entry for the built-in GPU, then you won't find one in the dmi output, and there's pretty much nothing you can do about it except complain to the vendor.

In general if you've got add-on cards, the only information you would get from smbios is the fact that one of the add-on slots is occupied. I would not expect a bios vendor to interrogate the add-on cards to populate this information as this information would not be considered 'built-in' to the motherboard.